# Samtools pysam mate

Tags: samtools, pysam

I am using pysam to dome data mining on .bam files. I want to check if a read has a mapped mate. The command

```
mate = samfile.mate(read1)
```

throws an error if the mate is not mapped, so if I do

```
if samfile.mate(read1): ...
```

that throws an error, too. Any other way to check if the read has a mapped mate?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

AlignedSegment.mate_is_unmapped should work for you. See [docs for pysam](http://pysam.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=mate_is_unmapped#pysam.AlignedSegment.mate_is_unmapped)

```
if not read1.mate_is_unmapped:
    mate = samfile.mate(read1)
    ...
```

Alternatively, you could just catch the exception and move on, but relying on exception handling for normal program flow is not ideal.